# merging 2 files into a third one, using columns as index and merging lines too

Tags: merge, awk, uniq

I've been studying awk and i've come upon a problem i'm not being able to solve, please help if you can.

I have 2 files I generated using awk, sort and uniq -c.

**File 1** is in the format:

```
1 aaa.c 10/10/2010

1 bbb.h 1/1/2011

3 ccc.c 2/2/2012

1 ccc.c 20/6/2011

1 ddd.c 1/1/2010

1 ddd.c 2/4/1999

1 ddd.c 7/1/2012

1 ddd.c 10/1/1977
```

*Meaning:* number_of_equal_files name date (so, 3 files ccc.c from the same date and 1 file ccc.c from another)

**File 2** is in the format:

```
4 ddd.c

2 ccc.c

3 xxx.c
```

*Meaning:* number_of_different_dates name (so, ccc.c has been found with 2 different dates) -> files that would have number=1 i removed usind a reverse grep, so there won't be any

What i'd like to do is to generate a third file in the format

number_of_different_dates name date1 date2 date 3 date4 (...)

something like:

```
2 ccc.c 2/2/2012 20/6/2011 

4 ddd.c 1/1/2010 2/4/1999 7/1/2012 10/1/1977
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh, and the files are ordered by name! i put the example in the wrong order, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get that result using only the first file as input.  The following uses two associative arrays.  The first collects the number of times a file is seen and the second collects the dates.  The `END` block just prints the entries that appeared more than once.

```
{
   counts[$2] += 1;
   dates[$2] = sprintf( "%s %s", dates[$2], $3 );
}

END {
   for ( f in dates ) {
      if ( counts[f] > 1 )
     printf( "%d %s %s\n", counts[f], f, dates[f]);
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for the quick reply! it doesnt show the number of different dates, but that's not important. i just added it here. thanks again!

Comment: @JonasTadeu:  Ah!  You are right; I didn't notice that in the example.  I updated the printf to add it in.

Comment: yeah, I did the same, only i put counts between f and dates.. anyway, its amazing.. it'll be so easy to erase useless files.. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR==FNR{
            a[$3]=$2; b[$2]++;next
       } 

($2 in b){
            printf ("%s %s ", $1,$2);
            for (i in a) 
                if (a[i]==$2) 
                    printf i" "; print ""
          }
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1
1 aaa.c 10/10/2010

1 bbb.h 1/1/2011

3 ccc.c 2/2/2012

1 ccc.c 20/6/2011

1 ddd.c 1/1/2010

1 ddd.c 2/4/1999

1 ddd.c 7/1/2012

1 ddd.c 10/1/1977

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2
4 ddd.c

2 ccc.c

3 xxx.c

[jaypal:~/Temp] ./s.awk ff1 ff2
4 ddd.c 10/1/1977 1/1/2010 2/4/1999 7/1/2012 

2 ccc.c 20/6/2011 2/2/2012
```

Comment: thanks for the answer too, but i chose Mark's cuz its a little easier to understand. thanks anyway!

Comment: Sure no problem. Just wanted to offer an alternate. :)